# Stripping base path off the unpacked source tree with bitbake SRC_URI file:// fetcher

Tags: yocto, bitbake

The manual [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#bb-the-unpack) says that there is a `basepath` option to `SRC_URI` that should "strip the specified directories from the source path when unpacking".

I'm trying to fetch the sources from a local directory, say `/src/someproject`.
For that purpose I configured my recipe as follows:

`SRC_URI="file:///src/someproject;subdir=source;basepath=/src/someproject"`

The intention was to have the sources taken from `/src/someproject` **directory** and put into `build/tmp/work/target/someproject/1.0-r1/source/`. Instead, I'm getting the sources under `build/tmp/work/target/someproject/1.0-r1/source/src/someproject`.

Is there a way to get rid of `/src/someproject` subdirectory inside `source` ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you point to is for yocto 1.6, release April 2014.  The `basepath` parameter appears to have been removed in later releases, with no fanfare and no apparent replacement.

Instead you can do something like:

```
SRCDIR = "/path/to/your/files"
SRC_URI = "file://${SRCDIR}/contents/;subdir=src"
S = "${WORKDIR}/src"
```

Then you can access your files under `${S}/${SRCDIR}`.

If you find using the `${SRCDIR}` part too cumbersome, you can hook onto the `do_patch` target, which need the `prefunc` mechanism and not `_prepend` if you want to use shell scripting, as `do_patch` is otherwise written in python:

```
relocate_source() {
  mv ${S}/${SRCDIR}/* ${S}/
  rmdir ${S}/${SRCDIR}
}
do_patch[prefunc] += "relocate_source"
```

This will reorganise your source before applying any patch you can add to `SRC_URI`.

Also note that a `file://` URI does not get cached in `${DL_DIR}`, so there is no name-conflict to handle (the way we would need to use `downloadfilename=` in an `http://` URI).

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding removal of the `basepath` parameter. It went away with [this commit](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/commit/e659a3b0c2771679057ee3e13cd42e6c62383ff2). Documentation was [updated](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/commit/76bf42ea41a28b19d0377c2e548b0a59119fdf67) a few years later.